# Unmount script running on unmounted device

Tags: usb-drive, scripts, mountpoint, umount

How can I unmount a USB drive using a script located on that drive?
The device appears busy when the script is running,

Comment: You should be able to make the script copy itself to `/tmp` or similar, run and detach the copy and exit itself. Otherwise you will still have a open file descriptor on the drive blocking unmounting.

Comment: @chronitis: how do I "run and detach the copy" in bash?

Comment: Normally a script owns any other scripts it starts, and does not exit until they do, even if they are started with `script &`. You want the parent script to really exit before the child script unmounts the drive, so *I think* you have to use `nohup` or similar to ensure the child survives the parent exiting. I'm not certain about the exact semantics however, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First attempt with `&`

```sh
#!/bin/sh -xv

#Get  device where I am located  
DEV=$(df -k "$0" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo $DEV

#Create umount script 
echo '#!/bin/sh -xv' >/tmp/udisk.tmp
echo "umount $DEV" >>/tmp/udisk.tmp
cat /tmp/udisk.tmp
chmod +x /tmp/udisk.tmp

#Run the script 
/tmp/udisk.tmp &
```